# Regular Expression Syntax (one specific string + the regular expressions)

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression that looks like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{2}[-zZ][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,7}[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}[a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z0-9]?", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid part number.")]
```

That allows for part numbers like this 07-287370-002 or 11-16D897-007.

I would also like the regular expression to accept this specific value:
     ##-######-###

I am unsure of the syntax, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression that says `(A|B)` means "accepts a string matching expression `A` or expression `B`". Thus, you would do:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(##-######-###|\d{2}[-zZ][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,7}[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}[a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z0-9]?)", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid part number.")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d{2}[-zZ][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,7}[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}[a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z0-9]|##-######-###?", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid part number.")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be say try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\d{2}[-zZ][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,7}[-a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3}[a-zA-Z0-9]?[a-zA-Z0-9]?;
String PI = "Enter sample part number here to check"
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(PI);
    String partNumTemp = "";
    if(matcher.find()){
        partNumTemp = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(partNumTemp);

    }else{
        System.out.println("Did not work sorry");
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't relate to the question at all, which is about matching the specific value "##-######-###". The question isn't even in Java (while I could be wrong, I believe it is in C#)